# Is Ionic 3 incompatible w/ OneSignal?

Tags: push-notification, push, onesignal

My app is created with Ionic 3 and my OneSignal push notifications stopped working. I've got a team working on it saying that it's incompatible since it's supposedly "outdated" language and doesn't work well with OneSignal.

Answer (score 1):

`Onesignal` still support ionic 3 but you have to install the v4 @ionic/native and the latest onesignal cordova plugin

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
  ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin --save
  npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal@4
```

To read more about the plugin you can see Ionic official website for `ionic3/Onesignal` from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/onesignal/) and the `Onesignal` documentation home page which have a tab for `Ionic CLI v3` that still support from [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup)